# Can't get Xdebug to work on Windows 7

Tags: php, apache, windows-7, xampp, xdebug

I installed the latest XAMPP package which includes PHP 5.3.0. I am trying to enable Xdebug, but it just won't work.

Here's what I changed in the php.ini shipped with XAMPP:

```
; uncommented
zend_extension = "X:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll"

; added the following lines:
xdebug.remote_enable=true
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
```

Apache starts fine, but when I open `http://localhost/` in my browser, I get the following error:

[image]

If I click the `Close the program` button, the error message will reappear in a second as if it was in an infinite loop. I'd greatly appreciate **any** help in getting this to work.

I am running a fresh install of Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit.

EDIT:
From the result of phpinfo():

```
Zend Extension Build    API220090626,TS,VC6 
PHP Extension Build     API20090626,TS,VC6 
Debug Build             no 
Thread Safety           enabled
```

Answer (score 4):

It's possible you have the wrong version of Xdebug.  I would take a look at [phpinfo()](http://php.net/phpinfo) and compare the information there to the [different versions of the Xdebug dll](http://xdebug.org/download.php).

Specifically, you want to see if "Thread Safety" is enabled, and you need to know whether you're running a VC6-compiled PHP or a VC9 (if you're using Apache, it's almost guaranteed that you want the VC6).

Comment: Thread safety is enabled. PHP is complied with VC6. I grabbed thread-safe 5.3 VC6 and neither the 32-bit flavor nor the 64-bit flavor is loaded. However, Apache doesn't crash anymore.

Comment: This is helpful, I had php 5.4 but was trying to install 5.3 dll which did not give an error though.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried custom installation wizard of XDEBUG, it analyses your php installation and provides exact steps you need to follow

The Windows binaries generally work for every mini release for the mentioned PHP version, although the extension is built against the most current PHP version at that time. The VCx marker tells with which compiler the extension was built, and Non-thread-safe whether ZTS was disabled. Those qualifiers need to match the PHP version you're using. If you don't know which one you need, please refer to the custom installation instructions.

http://xdebug.org/wizard.php

Just paste your phpinfo out put in the text box and you will get exact xdebug dll you would need for your php

Comment: This is brilliant. The only issue is that it installs it directly into PHP, so you'll need a bit more tweaking in order to run it from the command line - which is what some tools do.

Comment: The wizard saved me, nothing else I tried worked. Ended up being absolute vs. relative path.

Answer (score 2):

frank-ly, I also had 2 REALLY bad days, and I don't now what finally fixed it, 
so here's my collection of Do's and pitfalls:

```
; this is the thread safe version,
; the absence of _nts_ in the dll name 'shows' this
; do not use _ts, your library won't get registered and won't show in phpInfo()
zend_extension = "D:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.8/zend_ext/php_xdebug-2.1.2-5.3-vc9-x86_64.dll"
```

check your php.ini, check phpinfo() if all values (arrive)

```
xdebug.remote_enable = on
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.profiler_enable = off
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = off
; if you have multiple virtual hosts ( like 'local.fooclient' )
; maybe using the IP is safer (for any same-machine-debugging)
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
; maybe a -much- lower port helped, 84 was free. use netstat to figure out.
xdebug.remote_port=84
; idekey! also see note below
xdebug.idekey=netbeans-xdebug
```

**More Pitfalls:**

I have seen a typo of xdebug.remote_handle (without r) several times on the web. beware.

A note on the idekey: The above idekey did show in phpinfo() as master value, BUT
was overridden with a 'local value' like MYMACHINENAME$. ==> Setting a global env var (in computer properties) named DBGP_IDEKEY and rebooting (or maybe just logging out) to (also) netbeans-xdebug helps! Again: re-check in phpInfo() it took effect.

Of course adjust netbeans-menu:options->php tab->debugging section to this port and session id.

[Here](http://blogs.oracle.com/netbeansphp/entry/howto_check_xdebug_installation) is a script, to check (by php means) if that port you intend to talk to is open. (further below also in the comments, for those to lazy too type from the image)

For your browser to connect, don't start to forget (amidst frustration) to always attach the debug-starting get-argument:

```
  http://localhost/myTest.php?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=netbeans-xdebug
```

On the *port frontier*, also [this tool](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-en/sysinternals/bb897437) might help.

Quadruplecheck you are keeping VC6 and VC9 compiled versions of everything apart.

Running your `whatever/path/php.exe myTest.php` from the command line (once the above settings are done) might also reveal additional errors (it did, while I was tinkering with an incorrect dll).

I can recommend http://www.wampserver.com
(for personal reasons it fits me better than the popular xampp package...)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a known problem - is almost impossible to get Xdebug working with latest Xampp and 64-bit Vista/Win 7.

There is a [bug](http://bugs.xdebug.org/view.php?id=410) reported with many users complaining about it.

The solution seems to be [latest beta version on Xampp](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-beta.html). It includes version 2.0.6 (dev) of xdebug and it is working just fine.

I tested it on 64-bit Vista for approx 10 days and not encountered any problem yet.

Answer (score 0):

Like others have said, you need to match your xdebug version with your php version.

You've already matched up PHP version number, thread safety, and compiler.

If you haven't already figured it out (this is an old thread), **what you're missing is the INI configuration.** If you are loading a module that's thread safe, you need to use the following line:

```
zend_extension="C:\Path\To\The\Extension.dll"
```

If the module is *not* thread safe, then you use the INI directive you've been trying to use.

This only applies to zend_extension's and not regular extensions.

Comment: Note: Using a _ts is NOT correct for Apache 2.2.21, PHP 5.3 under W7 x64, even if PHP and Apoache is TS, use the normal key (just assign the correct dll to it, the one, that does not bear an _nts_ in it). Maybe it was correct some time back.

Comment: You are correct, doubt anyone will ever see my post at this point but I updated it

Answer (score 0):

When xdebug is installed not with XAMPP, just with PHP (32bit, TS, VC6, in C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP) and Apache (32bit) on Windows 7 (64bit), in *php.ini* you need to specify the full path to **x86** folder of Program Files like.

```
zend_extension="C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\ext\php_xdebug-2.1.1-5.3-vc6.dll"
```

and **NOT**

```
zend_extension="C:\Program Files\PHP\ext\php_xdebug-2.1.1-5.3-vc6.dll"
```

This was my mistake, when changed to x86 folder, xdebug started to work perfectly. Hope this help you, too.